# jQuery - Selecting a column in HTML table through text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this kind of structure in my table

```
<table>
    <c:forEach ...>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td> // i have this value
        <td>random value</td>
        <td>random value</td>
        <td>random value</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I have the text of the first `<td>`. I want to change the **text of any of the following** `<td>` **desire after the first one** using jQuery or any suggestion you have. I really having a hard time thinking of how I can do this.

Can anyone please help me?

EDIT: ( i.e. I want to change the 2nd `<td>` you could say `$('#td2').text('test');` );

Comment: *'any of the following `<td>` desire after the first one'* - what does that even mean? Change the text to *what*? Based on what event or user-interaction?

Comment: @DavidThomas what I mean is to change any of its sibling `<td>` depending on any you assign. ( i.e. I want to change the 2nd `<td>` you could say `$('#td2').text('test');` ); I want to change it dynamically. And the text doesn't matter because I will be the one to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//this holds the text to be searched
var text = 'text';
//use .filter() to find the td because :contains can return partial matches
var $tr = $('table td:first-child').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == text
}).parent();
var $tds = $tr.find('td');//this is all the tds in the row
$tds.eq(1).text('updated');//use the index to update the content
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u4kzU/)

Comment: This is exactly what am I looking for. I just need to modify this a bit, depending on what I need. Thanks again, your always a good help, including in the past.

Answer (score 0):

This will update the 2nd `TD` with `jQuery`:

```
$(function() {
    $('table tr td:nth-child(2)').html('updated');
});
```

You could write a loop to iterate and do this across as many cells as you 'desire'.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8Ngb/4/)

Answer (score 0):

use below jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr :not(:first-child)").text("NEW TEXT");
});
```

look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGFyk/)